# How to collect the syslog in openwrt?

Tags: raspberry-pi, syslog, openwrt

I want to collect the whole log file of the openwrt in raspberry pi-3 system,as it will be available in /var/log/syslog in normal system.Please help me to collect the whole syslog of the raspberry pi-3 openwrt OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `dmesg` command to collect kernel log

Comment: Yes ,from where the log message is popping out like in normal systems it will be from /var/log/syslog like that.

Answer (score 2):

uci default using the logread to get the log. You can see more detail in openwrt webside. 
https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/base-system/log.essentials

Comment: Could you please explain in detail why this solves the problem instead of just posting a link to the documentation without additional information?

Comment: The official page describes how to configure and use the logging system.